# Can not deserialize a simple json

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

I do not understand why i get the following error when deserializing json

> Message: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.

**Model**

```
class Messages
    {
        public object []Items { get; set; }
    }
```

**Json**

```
{
  "Items": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

**P.S** For the sake of simplicity i deleted all fields of my array objects and still i get the error.

Comment: Could you share your code for deserialization

Comment: I'm just using  `NewtonSoft'`'s `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XWOSlC).  Are you sure you are actually passing the JSON string to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, as opposed to a file path or some other string?